# Is it "a/the split" or "the splits"?

Tags: difference, usage, idiomatic-language

Would you please tell me which one is idiomatic one. Or what is the difference in the context of spreading ones legs. I am bit confused since I see both usages on the internet:

1. He's so flexible, he can do a/the split.
2. He's so flexible, he can do the splits.

Here is the Ngram results:

[image]

Comment: You have answered your own question. Look at the right end of the graph, from 1950 onward. Clearly, "do the splits" is the most idiomatic when referring to the act of spreading one's legs painfully on the floor to show off one's flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both *"do the splits"* and *"do a split"* are correct. There are two different types of splits: the side split and the front split.

It is perfectly idiomatic to say

> I was able to *do a split* after 3 months of training.

You might then be asked "Which one?" If you are able to do both, you say

> I am able to *do the splits*.

"to do a split" can be correct too depending on context.

> I want to be able to *do a split*.

is correct; you are just not concerned about which one. You only care about achieving at least one of them (usually the other one follows).

> Student 1: What are the requirements for the Taekwondo Level 2 class?
>
> Student 2: So, you gotta be able to do the pike, a split, and the basic 4 kicks to get into the advanced evening class. <sup>Either of the two splits will work</sup>

When we talk about flexibility, we usually say *"the splits"* (the plural) and not *"the split"*. But if your audience knows that you are particularly talking about the side split (or the front split), then you can use *"the split"* (singular) to refer to it after the first instance.

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer, it makes a lot more sense now. Thank you AIQ.

Comment: @Cardinal But note that I can't do either ...